# How to pass foreach loop failure detail to Catch block

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have some C# code whereby a foreach loop is used to retrieve data from an external website and this is matched and inserted into a database. This is vunerable to breaking so I've surrounded it with a try/catch block. I'd like to pass details of which member of the collection the loop failed on (in this case the Player.Name property).

However, when I catch the exception all I get is a Null Reference Exception message without any details of where the error originated. Is there a way to pass this info to the catch block so that I can then send it on to my view?

```
      try
        {
            document = getHtmlWeb.Load("http://example.com/");

            foreach (Player player in players)
            {
                string pointsString="ExampleString"+player.Name;

                    pointsString = document.DocumentNode
                    .SelectSingleNode(pointsString)
                    .InnerText;

            // other code inserting data to database
            }


            return View();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options - The best option:  Move the try/catch inside the foreach loop, so you have access to your player:

```
foreach (Player player in players)
{
    try
    {
        string pointsString="ExampleString"+player.Name;
        pointsString = document.DocumentNode
        .SelectSingleNode(pointsString)
        .InnerText;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Use player here, break out of the 
        // foreach loop if necessary.
        return View("Error at player " + player.Name);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could store the last player outside of your try/catch:

```
Player lastPlayerParsed;

try
{
    document = getHtmlWeb.Load("http://example.com/");

    foreach (Player player in players)
    {
        lastPlayerParsed = player;
        string pointsString="ExampleString"+player.Name;

            pointsString = document.DocumentNode
            .SelectSingleNode(pointsString)
            .InnerText;
    }

    return View();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    if (lastPlayerParsed != null) // It could bomb before the foreach!
    {
        return View("Error at player " + lastPlayerParsed.Name);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** On a side note, your `NullReferenceException` may be actually caused by your capitialization in your foreach loop, if your code you copied is accurate:

```
foreach (Player player in players)
{
    string pointsString= "ExampleString" + Player.Name;
```

You probably mean for `Player` to be lowercase here, since `Player.Name` will refer to a static property on the `Player` class.

Comment: thanks yeah that was just a typo when I was editing the code in here

Answer (score 1):

First, I can't see in your code where players is set, so that might explain the null reference. Secondly, I would recommend creating your own exception class. If you do that, you can add whatever properties you like to it.

[Custom Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cdya3t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)